# Why is Java not able to infer the type?

Tags: java, comparator, type-inference

So I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
  String id;
  String name;
  // getter/setter/constructor omitted
}
```

and a working Comparator:

```
Comparator<MyClass> myComparator = Comparator
            .comparing(MyClass::getName)
            .thenComparing(MyClass::getId)
```

Everything is ok until then, but I was wondering why by changing the Comparator as shown below we get a compilation error at `comparing`:

```
Comparator<MyClass> myComparator = Comparator
            // m is infered to Object
            .comparing(m -> m.getId())
            .thenComparing(MyClass::getName);
```

It is in my understanding that `m` should be inferred to `MyClass`, but it does not seem like it. We need to explicitly cast the lambda parameter:

```
Comparator<MyClass> myComparator = Comparator
            .comparing((MyClass m) -> m.getId())
            .thenComparing(MyClass::getName);
```

N.B.: Tested with JDK 11 and 14.

Comment: Why do you assume java should be able to deduce the type? The argument type is `Function<? super T,? extends U>`. Java only has your argument to deduce that type, but there is no information.

Comment: `(MyClass m)` ← That is not a cast.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer If the type inference were cleverer, it could infer it from the type of the target, the variable.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer Technically, it is possible to safely infer the type in this case. It's just that Java doesn't do it. Swift, for example, _can_ infer it.

Comment: @Michael well, if you look at the type of Comparator, you can compare a T and a U (e.g., String 'compare' MyClass). So even though Java looks at the return type, that doesn't help you in deducing the input type in this case.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer The T in the parameter and the return are the same. So if you know the return should be `Comparator<MyClass>`, you can infer the parameters are MyClass and U. U can be inferred from the return of the `getId()` method. It is certainly possible to infer it, the compiler just is not that sophisticated.